# what is the difference between socket and sock?

Tags: linux, sockets

I found that there is "socket: /tmp/mysql.sock" in some config files, so what is the difference between socket and sock ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Socket' is the technical term for a handle that refers to a network endpoint. It originated in the Unix API for networks, and has since leaked over to Windows.

A socket can refer to TCP connection, a UDP packet endpoint, an X.25 connection, or ... a Unix domain socket, which is a mutant named pipe.

People tend to name Unix domain sockets with 'sock' in the name, but there's no requirement.

Answer (score 4):

`sock` is an abbreviation of `socket` (also a sock is something that is worn on the feet).

Answer (score 3):

Sock is just an abbreviation for socket.  But if you see a socket as a file it's a Unix socket as opposed to a TCP socket.

This link has some information on the differences between the two.
http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-performance/2005-February/001143.html

Basically a TCP socket communicates over the network, and a Unix socket is similar except it can only connect to your localhost.  (`127.0.0.1`)